# Formatting a date from a NSString

Tags: objective-c

I am creating a NSDateCategory that formats a date but it always returns null, any ideas?

> 2011-06-05T16:55:00Z

```
+ (NSDate *)dateFromString:(NSString *)dateString
{
    NSLog(@"date string %@", dateString);

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd+hh:MM:ss"];
    NSDate *result = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
    [dateFormatter release];
    return result;
}
```

Comment: could you please post the date strings you tested with....

Comment: Please see the second line of the question for the date string

Comment: ooops - .. posted an answer anyway. And think I was right. You tried to parse a date with month 55.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What a huge mission!  Finally figured it out.  The timezone needs to be set before you even worry about the formatting!

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
    NSDate *result = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
    [dateFormatter release];
```

Answer (score 2):

Your string and your format don't match. You used a "T" in the date string to separate the time and ended with a time zone indicator. Your format uses a "+" to separate the time and has not timezone indicator. You also used "MM" for minutes, which should "mm".

See [UTS#35](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns) for the symbols used in the formatter string.

Comment: Z is not a proper time zone in UTS#35. It stands for UTC ("zulu time"). You can either do a substitution on it to swap "Z" to "UTC" or you can use a literal "Z" if it'll always be there. yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'. Note the single quotes around the literals and the use of HH rather than hh. Please be sure to read the referenced table.

Answer (score 1):

I assuem it should be `dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd+hh:mm:ss"];` (**mm** is for minutes)